# How to pass state from child component to parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the parent component called `App`, and a child component called `Left`.

`Left` component has a couple of components called `Settings` and `NotesList`

```
class Left extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { isAddNewNoteClicked: false };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <Settings onNew={this.onNewNote.bind(this)} />
        <NotesList newNote={this.state.isAddNewNoteClicked} />
      </section>
    );
  }

  onNewNote = (isAddNewNoteClicked) => {
    this.setState({ isAddNewNoteClicked });

    {/* SEE EDIT */}
    {/* this.props.onNewNote(this.state.isAddNewNoteClicked); */}

    {/* SEE EDIT #2 */}
    this.props.onNewNote(isAddNewNoteClicked);
  }
}
```

`Settings` component has a button that will pass `isAddNewNoteClicked` as `true` when clicked.

**the state is being passed up to `Left` without a hitch**, but my problem is passing `isAddNewNoteClicked` from `Left` to `App`.

`<App />` looks like this

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { isAddNewNoteClicked: false };
  }

  onNewNote = () => {
    console.log('test');
  }

  testFunction(a) {
    console.log('test', a);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main className="App">
        <Left onNew={this.testFunction.bind(this)} />
        <Right isAddNewNoteClicked={ this.state.isAddNewNoteClicked } />
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

so I added `this.props.onNewNote(this.state.isAddNewNoteClicked);` to the `onNewNote` function on my `<Left />` component and it's now calling that function, but the state on the `' is not being updated...

**EDIT #2**

instead of `this.props.onNewNote(this.state.isAddNewNoteClicked);` I added the variable itself instead of that from the state and it's working now.

Comment: so you just need your child component response in your parent component?

Comment: Yeah so that I could pass that state into another child component (ie <Right />)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so adding this line

```
this.props.onNewNote(isAddNewNoteClicked);
```

on the `onNewNote()` function on my `<Left />` fixed the issue.

Hope it helped someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Your Left component is not calling the onNew function that was passed to it via props from App. This part

```
onNewNote = (isAddNewNoteClicked) => {
  this.setState({ isAddNewNoteClicked });
}
```

will only set the state for Left until you call this.props.onNew()

## Edit

On Left

```
onNewNote = (isAddNewNoteClicked) => {
  this.setState({ isAddNewNoteClicked });
  this.props.onNew(isAddNewNoteClicked); // Notice you calling it "onNew", not "onNewNote"
}
```

on App

```
testFunction(isAddNewNoteClicked) {
  this.setState({ isAddNewNoteClicked })
}
```

Comment: Kindly see my edit sir. State is now being updated but only after two clicks. It's not updating on the first click!

Answer (score 0):

For this, Parent has send the value to its child as props. so, we are get that in our child component by props.

By the following way.

```
this.props.onNewNote(this.state.isAddNewNoteClicked);
```